# On running redis-CLI my connection is being cancelled everytime

Tags: django, redis

**RESOLVED**

I'm trying to learn Redis with Django framework. My program is intended to count image views but when I click on the image details it gives me above mentioned error. I am unable to make connection with redis.
Here's the link to my detail error http://dpaste.com/1TAJ4MF

I have installed and run redis cli on WINDOWS 10 and here is a snip of my settings.py code

```
# Configuring Redis database
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6397
REDIS_DB = 0
```

**views.py**

```
import redis
from django.conf import settings


def detail(request, id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=id)
    # increment total image views by 1
    total_views = r.incr('profile:{}:views'.format(profile.id))


    return render(request, 'images/detail.html', {'profile': profile, 'total_views': total_views})
```

**detail.html**

```
<body>

  <img src="{{ profile.photo.url }}" width="500" height="500" alt="Image not found">
  <br>
  {{ profile.user.username.title }}. 
  {{ profile.dob }}
  <br>
  {{ total_views }} view{{ total_views|pluralize }}
</body>
```

Comment: Are you certain Redis is running?

Comment: Yes, when I run the redis CLI file its running and replying 'pong' on my 'ping' command.